# Using SQL function from SQL handling class in other functions

Tags: php, sql, class, function

I have created an SQL function `SQLquery` in a class called `SQLHandling`
It looks like this:

```
 /***********************************************************
    * SQLquery takes a full SQL query and runs it
    * If it fails it will return an error otherwise it will return
    * the SQL query as given.
    ************************************************************/   
    function SQLquery($query)  { 

        $q = mysql_query($query);

        if(!$q) {
            die(mysql_error());
            return false;
        } else {
            return $q;          
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway I can use this function in other classes functions without adding

```
$db = new SQLHandling();
$db->SQLquery($sql);
```

In every function where I will use it.

I know I can run `SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql);` but I am trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instantiate SQLHandling on class level, like so:

```
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new SQLHandling();
    }

    public function x()
    {
        $this->db->query('X');
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Spot on!
Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

use inheritance

refer:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

but still you will need to use parent::fun() or $this->fun()
or put it as a public function then use any where.

example:

```
<?php

function c()
{
        echo "moi";
}    

class b extends a
{       
   public function d(){

    parent::c();//Hai
    $this->c();//Hai
    c();//moi

    }   


}


class a{    



    public function c(){
        echo "Hai";

    }       
} 


$kk = new b();
$kk -> d();

?>
```

Comment: You are suggesting he should extend SQLHandling in other classes? I don't see any reason to do so..